# about push notification and publishing an application ios

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, identifier

In my first application version, I didn't implement the push notification, but I will implement it in the second version, my question is when I create an Identifier to publish my application in app store, shall I check the push notification service? or not?

Comment: Not required. You can configure push notifications when you are submitting the second version of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your AppID later in the future will work, unless you are using a wildcard character (*) on it.

If your AppID is something like:

> com.me.myApp

Will work, but something like this:

> com.me.*

Wont

So just be sure your AppID is correct.

Comment: I am not using wild *, I am using com.me.myApp

Comment: Then everything is going to be fine. Please accept the answer if it worked

Comment: so, I can keep the push notification check box unchecked?

Comment: Yes, and check it later when you send your second version